# Complex integration with $\epsilon$ and $\pi$.

Tags: complex-integration

I'm not sure how to solve this integral:

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{dz}{(e^z+4)(z-\pi i)}, $$

where $ \gamma$ is the region $ \|z-\sqrt7i\|+\|z+\sqrt7i\|=8$.

I know that region is the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1 $ but I don't know how to solve the integral. I tried to use Taylor series but got nothing.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral formula with residues?

Comment: Right. I did not realize I could solve the case, using Cauchy's integral formula with residues. Thanks @Paul.